# mysql and php fetch_assoc() not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
//get average from all reviews

$allreviews = "SELECT round(avg(Stars_overall),0) AS average FROM (SELECT Stars_overall FROM Reviews WHERE Meal_ID = 1 ORDER BY Order_ID DESC LIMIT 5) AS Average";

$getresult = mysqli_query($conn, $allreviews);

$row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getresult);
echo "aaaaa" .$row3['average'].   "bbbbb";



mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Unfortunately it is not working, any clue why? It is for a review system, i'm trying to display an average of star ratings stored in database. The first sql gets all the ratings for a specific meal and the second sql calculates the average. I then want to be able to display the average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using mysqli, therefore you must use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and not `mysql_fetch_assoc`.